# Maple - subscripted variable T_0 isn't evaluated

Tags: maple

I have a subscripted variable T_0 in Maple with a value assigned to it T_0 := 1.

When I call the variable by entering T_0 in math mode, T_0 is displayed instead of 1. This doesn't happed for non-subscripted variables.[image]

Why are subscripted variables not evaluated? I noticed this only happens for the variable name T and not for a; a_0 works.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that whitespaces after the index in the subscript are interpreted by Maple. Removing these whitespaces solved the problem.